# How much water should I give a mung bean each day?

Tags: vegetables, watering, indoors, technique, beans

I have a mung bean plant I'm growing in my home that's about 10 centimeters tall now. How much water should I be giving the plant each day in order for it to grow? I would like to know the amount in cubic centimeters if possible.

Comment: i have a `mung bean` or `vigna radiate` in my home.
i don't know how much i must water it per day for grow.
`golden gram` the other name for this in english.

Comment: Do you have it as just a bean you planted recently, or is it a sprouted?

Comment: @MattS. recently.  
they are now 10 cm height.

Comment: Please give more information. How old is the plant? Or when did you get it? How big is it? Do you have space for it outdoors? What kind of light and temperatures is it receiving?

Comment: thanks @MattS. and  J. Musser for answer.  
1 week old. perhaps 6 day.  
they are 5-15 cm height and (< 0.5) cm width.
i have a Pots with x = 25 cm . y = 15 cm . z = 13 cm .
but i change it soon as possible.
i'am an Late Summer with normal temperatures . not cold and not warm. its now in dark with artificial light.

Comment: Apparently more than I gave ours last year (which was every couple days or so). They just germinated and died. It might have been the clay-loam soil, our climate, or the scarcity of direct sunlight, though (ours weren't potted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's dangerous to use a set amount of water per day, when watering potted plants. This is because they may use different quantities as they get older, and also because it is very easy to overwater, which could be fatal. It's better to water until the mix is wet, and then leave it until the top ½" of soil becomes dry. Use your finger to test this. You can then water again. This ensures that you aren't overwatering. Make sure the water drains well from the bottom of the pot, and that you don't let the pot sit in a saucer containing sitting water.

Mung beans will do much better outside, if you can find a place for them, so long as it's warm out. They require lots of light, so you may need additional lighting indoors.

Comment: @itsmatt Yup, it's the way to go - I never recommend using a set ration for watering. On another note, I hit my rep cap at 18:01 so the last ten upvotes I've gotten were empty. My own fault for answering everything.

Comment: you are the 'Jon Skeet' of Gardening & Landscaping - If you're not familiar with him, he's got the highest rep of all time on stackoverflow. =)  I'm always impressed by your thorough responses.